# add a unique id to each matched pattern in file

Tags: bash

I have a file containing some asserts.

```
...
  assert p1;
...
  assert p2;
```

I need to give a unique id to each assert

```
...
  {uniqueId:0} assert p1;
...
  {uniqueId:1} assert p2;
```

Is there a way to do in bash using basic unix commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for something like

```
perl -pe 's/assert/$c++." $&"/e' file 
...
  0 assert p1;
...
  1 assert p2;
```

This assumes that the only lines that contain `assert` are the ones that you want to change. I cannot tell from your example input if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^ *assert/{$0 = "{uniqueId:" i++ "} " $0}1' file
...
{uniqueId:0}   assert p1;
...
{uniqueId:1}   assert p2;
```